# Dynamically high chart rendering not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, rendering, gatsby

I have parent component in which I have used the parent highchart component. Something like this

```
class MobHome extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Link to="/graphdetails">
        <AreaSplineChart
          id="1keyTotalVisitor"
          key="keyTotalVisitor"
          className="graph-visitor"
          title="<strong>Total Visitors</strong>"
          subtitle={`This is all the users that have visited your <br/> site.
             <br/><span style='font-size:60px; color: #5BC0BE; font-weight:600'>
             ${ analyticsData.totalVisitors }</span>`}
          data={_.get(analyticsData, 'totalVisitorsGraphData', []).map(t => t.count)}
          categories={_.get(analyticsData, 'totalVisitorsGraphData', []).map(t => t._id)}
          filterType={this.state.filterType}
          graphData={_.get(analyticsData, 'totalVisitorsGraphData', [])}
        />
      </Link>
    )
  }
}
```

And my highchart(child) component looks Something like this

```
componentWillReceiveProps (np) {
  if (this.props.data !== np.data) {
    this.highChartFunction(np)
  }
}
class AreaSplineChart extends Component {
  highChartFunction () {
    const { title, subtitle, id, data, categories, graphData } = this.props
    console.log(id)
    Highcharts.chart(String(id), {
      //... options
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { id } = this.props
    console.log(id)
    return (
      <div key={id} id={id}/>
    )
  }
}
export default AreaSplineChart
```

Now the issue is working correct in my development mode but gives error in production mode.

```
Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13
```

I have console logs everywhere I am sure my `ids` first renders and then my function being called. But still I am getting the issue. Is there any with gatsby production build or I am doing something wrong here?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Would you mind sharing more of your code? For example where you call your `highChartFunction` method.

Comment: hi @Rallen Updated my answer. pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error given by the `Highchart` library means that it could not find the div with the `id` you provided. It would seem that `componentWillReceiveProps` is called before render.

I would recommend you call your `highChartFunction` inside the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method and save the `Chart` instance to a class property to access it later. `componentDidMount` is called right after first call to `render`, so the element should be created at this point.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.highChartFunction();
}

highChartFunction () {
    const { title, subtitle, id, data, categories, graphData } = this.props;

    this.chart = Highcharts.chart(String(id), {
      //... options
    });
}
```

If you want to handle updates to the props I would recommend using `componentDidUpdate`, as `componentWillReceiveProps` is marked for deprecation and is planned to be removed in React 17. Also there seemed to be some bugs with it. `componentDidUpdate` gets the previous `props` as an argument so you can check if a update is needed:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if ("somehow prevProps and this.props is different") { // Replace with check
        this.chart.update({
            // new options
        }, /* Here is an argument to set if the chart should be rerendered, you can set it if necessary */);
    }
}
```

Also don´t forget to set the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method to destroy the chart:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.chart.destroy();
}
```

---

**Personal recommendation**: I would not use the `id` to set the chart, but instead use [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref). Those are references to the component which is in my opinion much better than an `id` lookup.

```
constructor() {
    this.chartContainer = React.createRef();
}

highChartFunction() {
    /* ... */
    Highcharts.chart(this.chartContainer.current, { ... });
}

render() {
    const { id } = this.props;
    return (<div key={id} id={id} ref={this.chartContainer} />)
}
```

---

[Here is a minimal example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o7jqp6254z) with all I have mentioned here.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! One of my collegue has remove the `componentDidMount` function.